# How to remove last fragment added to back stack without bringing it up to the screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity A and inside it I can have the fragments F1, F2 and F3, but only one at a time.

If the user goes from F1 to F2, and then presses the back button, he should go back to F1. I'm implementing this behaviour using the function addToBackStack.

However, if the users goes from F2 to F3, and presses the back button he shouldn't be taken to neither F1 nor F2. The app should remove A from back stack(exit the app in my case). So what I need is a way to remove the F1-F2 transaction once the user goes from F2 to other fragment, while keeping the behaviour explained in the last paragraph(back button on F2 takes user that back to F1).

When I use addToBackStack, F2 correctly takes the user back to F1, but then if he goes from F2 to F3 and presses back, he goes back to the previous fragment, which is not what I want.

Any thoughts on how to achieve the desired behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just finish Activity A on back press in Fragment F3 ?

Comment: There are other fragments in the same situation as F3(F4, F5, F6), but I thought I wouldn't mention them to make the question simpler. So I would have to add a piece of code in each of them to finish Activity A. While I might end up leaning to that solution, I was wondering if there isn't a more elegant one, something like removing the last object of the back stack when the user browses from F2 to any other fragment, so that F2 itself handles that.